# assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Werror=int-conversion]

Tags: arrays, c

Im trying to copy a char array to a bidimensional char array, but i keep getting this error message: `assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Werror=int-conversion]`.

It's weird because they're both char arrays of both 20 "slots"

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int entrada(char arg);
void procesado(int input);


char txt[20];
int prodAlm, prodPan, prodFre, prodBaz, prodDes;
char prodAlmLiq[2000][20];
char prodBazLiq[2000][20];

int main(){

    while(1){
        procesado(entrada(0));
    }

    return 0;

}

int entrada(char arg){
    int res;

    switch(arg){
        case 0:
            printf("Ingrese el codigo del producto: ");
            scanf("%d", &res);
            return res;

            break;
        case 1:
            printf("Ingrese el codidigo del producto: (max. 12 caract.)");
            scanf("%s", txt);
            return 0;

            break;
        case 2:
            printf("Ingrese el valor del producto: $");
            scanf("%d", &res);
            return res;

            break;
        case 3:
            printf("!!Ingrese una descripcion breve (max. 12 caract.): !! [NOT WORKING, INPUT ANY NUMBER]");
            scanf("%s", txt);
            return 0;

            break;
        case 4:
            printf("Ingrese el stock disponible: ");
            scanf("%d", &res);
            return res;

            break;
        case 5:
            printf("Ingrese la cantidad en gondolas disponible: ");
            scanf("%d", &res);
            return res;

            break;
        default:
            if (arg == 'u'){
                printf("Saliendo...");
                return res;

            } else {
                printf("Ingrese una opcion correcta!\n\r");
            }
            break;
    }

    return 0;

}


void procesado(int input){
    static int countAL, countBL;
    static int returning = 0;
    float tmp;

    if (input == 'u'){
        //returning = 1;;
        
    }

    if (!returning){
        switch(input){
        case 10:
            prodPan++;
            break;
        case 20:
            prodAlm++;
            prodAlmLiq[countAL][0] = countAL+1;
            tmp = entrada(2);
            prodAlmLiq[countAL+2][0] = txt;                                         //Pregunta por el precio del prod
            tmp = (float) prodAlmLiq[countAL+2][0];
            if(tmp >= 4.5 && tmp <= 5.5){
                prodAlmLiq[countAL+1][0] = entrada(1);                              //Pregunta codigo del prod
                prodAlmLiq[countAL+3][0] = entrada(3);                              //Pide descripcion del prod
                prodAlmLiq[countAL+4][0] = entrada(4);                              //Pregunta el stock disponible del prod
                prodAlmLiq[countAL+5][0] = entrada(5);                              //Pregunta cantidad en gondola del prod
                countAL = countAL + 6;                                              //Da la vuelta a la estructura del arreglo para empezar una nueva linea
            }
            break;
        case 30:
            prodFre++;
            break;
        case 40:
        prodAlm++;
            prodBazLiq[countBL][0] = countBL+1;
            tmp = entrada(2);
            prodBazLiq[countBL+2][0] = txt;                                         //Pregunta por el precio del prod
            tmp = (float) prodBazLiq[countBL+2][0];
            if(tmp >= 9 && tmp <= 11){
                prodBazLiq[countBL+1][0] = entrada(1);                              //Pregunta codigo del prod
                prodBazLiq[countBL+3][0] = entrada(3);                              //Pide descripcion del prod
                prodBazLiq[countBL+4][0] = entrada(4);                              //Pregunta el stock disponible del prod
                prodBazLiq[countBL+5][0] = entrada(5);                              //Pregunta cantidad en gondola del prod
                countBL = countBL + 6;                                              //Da la vuelta a la estructura del arreglo para empezar una nueva linea
            }

        break;
        default:
        prodDes++;

        break;
    }
    printf("----------------------------------------\n\r           Producto Agregado!\n\r----------------------------------------");
    }
    
}
```

errors ocurr at 98,35 and 115,35.

code is not finished yet, but i wont keep going until i can solve that error.

Thanks for helping!

Comment: That's the lines `prodAlmLiq[countAL+2][0] = txt;` and `prodBazLiq[countBL+2][0] = txt;` where `txt` is a global `char[20]` array and the others are global `char[2000][20]` arrays. The warning is about converting the type of `txt` (in this case `char*` because of automatic conversion) to the type of what is on the left side of the assignment (to `char`, whch is an integer type).

Comment: I don't understand how *"they're both char arrays of both 20 "slots"* has anything to do with it. You have to use a copy function like `strcpy` or `memcpy`. You can't just assign a whole array,. You have to copy each byte. The name of the array truncates to a pointer, hence the warning you get.

Comment: Kudos to your reaction of asking about the diagnostic. **Whatever you do, do not add a cast to make the warning/error go away!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

right here

```
prodAlmLiq[countAL + 2][0] = txt;
```

the left side is a `char`, the right side is a `char*`

its not clear what you are actually trying to do though. Maybe you want to copy the string in txt to prodAlmliq[countAL +]

if so

```
   strcpy( prodAlmLiq[countAL + 2] , txt);
```

is what you need

Answer (score 0):

The implicated lines are

> ```
>             prodAlmLiq[countAL+2][0] = txt;
> ```

and the similar

> ```
>             prodBazLiq[countBL+2][0] = txt;
> ```

`prodAlmLiq` and `prodBazLiq` are each defined as a `char[2000][20]`, so in each case, the item being assigned is a single `char`.  For its part, `txt` is defined as a `char[20]`, so it does not make sense to try to assign it to a single char.  The error message reflects the fact that the `txt` array is automatically converted to a pointer in this context (as in most others), and although C permits that to be converted onward to a `char`, that's very unlikely to be what you really wanted, and standard C in any case requires a cast to perform that conversion.

My best guess is that you want to copy *the contents* of `txt` into corresponding elements of the big arrays. supposing that `txt` contains a null-terminated string, you would use `strcpy` for that.  Example:

```
                strcpy(prodAlmLiq[countAL+2], txt);
```